# How to force React to accept server markup

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

On the first load I render my markup completely filled with data on the server.

This works well and the client sees it as a static html till the client-side React takes over. But this client-side code throws the markup away.

I stopped React from requesting the data per AJAX on the first load (because it's already there), only if I navigate client-side with a react-router `<Link>` to it.

But I can't force it to simply let the markup be, till the user interacts with it.

Comment: Posted answer if I understand the question correctly - if no - attach some code examples, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute. For example, create a new component wrapper like this and set `html` property:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.createMarkup() }>

    </div>;
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // attach some events
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    // detach some events
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
    return false;
  },

  createMarkup: function() {
    return {
      __html: this.props.html
    };
  }
});
```